# What is the correct way to compare static immutable strings and mutable strings in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, comparison, equality, inequality

I am new to Rust & I am having trouble to compare mutable strings and immutable strings.

Please find below a code block which should exit if "exit" is entered.
But I am having problem with the same and so I put in some lines to get the hang of the comparison.
But all is returning false.

How to write the comparison such that the comparison returns true?

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    

    let mut input_line = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut input_handler=stdin.lock();
    let exit_str=String::from("exit");
    println!("Output=={}","exit".eq(&exit_str));
    while exit_str.ne(&mut input_line){
        input_line = String::new();
        let _=input_handler.read_line(&mut input_line);
        print!("surrealdbcli:");
        println!("Your Input={}",input_line);
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",exit_str.eq(&input_line.as_str()));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}","exit".eq(input_line.as_str()));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",(String::from("exit")).eq((&input_line).into()));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}","exit".eq(&input_line));
        let temp_str=input_line.to_string();
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",(String::from("exit")).eq(&temp_str));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",String::from("exit").eq(&temp_str));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",temp_str.eq("exit"));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",exit_str.eq(&temp_str));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}","exit".eq(&temp_str));
        println!("Is your input \"exit\"? {}",(String::from("exit")).eq((&temp_str).into()));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your comparisons are fine, but using `read_line` will include the trailing newline character which makes it not equal to `"exit"`.

Comment: Also the natural way to compare strings would be with the equality operator. I.e. `input == "exit"`

Comment: Yes, it was a newline issue :( . Thanks for helping out.